# Responsive positioning icons on images using absolute

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place font-awesome icons on the top of images, it works if the images keeps stick in one location, but due to the screen size the images might move down and up  without the icons

for example

first case it work fine

[image]

second case  one image move down when zoom in but the icon doesn't 
[image]

Third case  all images move below each other but the icons don't

[image]

HTML code

```
<span class="images_wrapper">
    <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o delete_image delete_image"></i>
    <img src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/UTB8ROsoXwnJXKJkSaelq6xUzXXab.jpg">
</span>
```

Css

```
.images_wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.images_wrapper i {
    position: absolute;
    color: red;
}
```

How to make icons move with the images ?

https://jsfiddle.net/1vzd5ofv/1/

try to zoom in as mash as you can until the images move down

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your CSS - without it we can only guess what you've written.

Comment: you try giving your icon a `top: 0; left: 0;` position?

Comment: There are 2 css code only  and it always works if the images don't move, but I really don't know to to move  icons that has absolute  propriety with the images

Comment: @zgood   it tried it, but nothing changed

Comment: I will write the code in jsfiddle.net  to make it easier for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `left` and `top` for your icons.

```css
.images_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
}
img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.images_wrapper i {
    position: absolute;
    color: red;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="images_wrapper">
    <i>X</i>
    <img src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/UTB8ROsoXwnJXKJkSaelq6xUzXXab.jpg">
</span>

<span class="images_wrapper">
    <i>X</i>
    <img src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/UTB8ROsoXwnJXKJkSaelq6xUzXXab.jpg">
</span>

<span class="images_wrapper">
    <i>X</i>
    <img src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/UTB8ROsoXwnJXKJkSaelq6xUzXXab.jpg">
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you  it works like a charm , the trick is by using  display: inline-block;   but why ??

Comment: I removed all css codes except display: inline-block; and it worked

Comment: You're welcome, no, `inline-block` is just for demo, you can use `float` too.